# Unhide a Windows hidden folder in OS X

Tags: macos

I had a Windows 7 machine which I have now taken to work since I got myself a Macbook Pro. I used my external drive with my Windows machine earlier.

It had some hidden folders in the disk which I want to unhide right away and I only have a MacBook available at home. I am unable to get it done with that.

So how do I unhide a folder hidden in Windows using a Mac? (also on an external drive)

Answer (score 0):

You could download and burn a linux live CD like [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.org/), boot to the CD, mount the drive in Linux.
From my experience, I've been able to read hidden files and folders by default while doing this.
Then all you have to do is copy the files to a an external HDD or USB memory stick and then boot back into OSX and load them.

This might not work if the Windows 7 disk is encrypted.