# Unhide folder from hidden in osx

Tags: macos

How to unhide the folder?

[image]

[image]

No answer found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/299704/unhide-a-windows-hidden-folder-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
chflags nohidden Video
```

Or, to hide it again:

```
chflags hidden Video
```